# I want to find the location of a user, so i decited to get from there IP address

Tags: python, django

I found a code and it works perfectly, but I am not very clear about the function.

```
x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
```

so this is the function, i jut want to know how accurate and clear the function is.

If anyone can advice me how to modify or how perfect my code i it will be very helpful.

**Thank you**

Comment: We cannot help you without knowing what do you expect the code to do, your needs, etc. Please edite the answer with further details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.